# php two checkboxes into one

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I have two checkboxes in pagination of (first column and second column).

The first column of pagination checkbox is comes with array like this..

```
<td class="check-box-column" >
   <input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
<td>
```

Second column of pagination checkbox is come without array like this code...

```
<td class="check-box-column" ><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></td>
```

Both is under same form name but use different action using **name="submit_mult"** in the button name.

The first column is comes with array that allow me to select more then one checkboxes and do action by click button to delete rows.

The second column that are not comes with array, but allow me to do other action...

My question is that, there is way that can be done TWO checkboxes into ONE but using array and none array in one checkboxes!

AM

Comment: what do you mean by `TWO checkboxes into ONE `? , do you want to do two actions on click of one checkbox ?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, IDs need to be unique. Your question is really vague.

Comment: @putvande duplicate ids, though not semantically correct, is hardly a cause for concern on the php side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to make it work like here http://jsfiddle.net/UTqTS/2/

Your checkboxes must have same name

```
name="something[]"
```

And include this jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').on('click',function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var checkboxes = 'input:checkbox[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]';
            $(checkboxes).prop('checked', false);
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

If first checkbox will be selected other should be deselected.

Or You can edit jquery code to make it **work on classes**!! Than if the checkbox will have only the same class it will allow to **select only one checkbox with same class**

Comment: I'm sorry for not clear but none of above is working, there is another word i'm trying to say make clear is that is there is way that have One checkbox in first column and there is three buttons to take action, one for copy, delete or other, so what does it do is that select unlimited checkbox and decided what want to do with check box, want to delete it, then press delete button, want to copy then press copy button, or other, but it has to be one checkbox in first column so how can i use one array name or without array name, to make work all into ONE. hope this clear what i'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multidimensional array for check box as below

```
<input name="selector[0][]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<input name="selector[1][]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```